# What is antonym of changing in favour of something?

Tags: antonyms

We may say *The traffic light changed in favour of us*, which means it changed from red to green for us.

How can I use a similar structure to say it changed from green to red?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for the exact phrase you have given: "changed in favour of us", I would say "has gone against us", but that sounds too grand for traffic lights.

For traffic lights, I would just say "gone green" and "gone red".